# How to find the size of map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to print the size of map in javascript. I used the command `map.size` but the answer is coming 0 which is not correct.

Here is my source code:

```
<div id="demo" ></div>
<script>
    function add(test, key, value) {
        if (!test[key]) 
            test[key] = [value];
        else 
            test[key].push(value);
    }
    var mapp = new Map();
    var i,j,k=0;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      for (j=0;j<i;j++)
      add(mapp,i,j);
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="Map size are: "+ mapp.size;
</script>
```

Output: `Map size are: 0`

However, when I am printing the map entries:

```
for (var m in mapp)
{
        for (k=0;k<mapp[m].length;k++)
        document.write(mapp[m][k]+"  ");

      document.write("<br>");
}
```

I can see the output:

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3
```

Please tell me how to find the size of map and why the above code `mapp.size` is not working.

Comment: Do you mean `.length`?

Comment: You don't get items out of a `Map` with square brackets `[]`, you use `.get()`.

Comment: @swonder, Yes, the length of the map or the total number of keys in map.

Comment: No I mean instead of .size(), type `.length` for a number (size) of the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are treating `Map` like an `Array`. You should use `get` and `set` methods on map to use the inbuilt functions and not in the array fashion [ ]. Javascript cannot calculate the size of the map if you are not using it correctly

If you can't change the code, then you can have your own function to calculate the size

```
function getMapSize(x) {
    var len = 0;
    for (var count in x) {
            len++;
    }

    return len;
}

alert(getMapSize(mapp));
```

Answer (score 47):

You are treating `Map` like an array and using `[]` to access key/value items of it.  You need to use the actual methods of `Map`.  Instead of `[]`, use [`.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set).

Right now, you are setting the actual **properties** of the `Map` which are not the same as the actual tracked iterable k/v items stored by the data structure.

```js
// Incorrect
const m1 = new Map();

m1["foo"] = "bar";

console.log(m1.length); // undefined
console.log(m1.size); // 0

// Correct
const m2 = new Map();

m2.set("foo", "bar");

console.log(m2.length); // undefined
console.log(m2.size); // 1
```

Comment: @Arya What do you expect it to be?

Comment: but now i am getting trouble in printing the map entries by using `.get()`

Comment: @Arya Please add any relevant info that you can as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 9):

Refer [How to check if a Map or Set is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520583/how-to-check-if-a-map-or-set-is-empty).

It works with empty map as well as map with values.

var list = {};
console.log(Object.keys(list).length );

result = 0

list = {"key":"hello"};
console.log(Object.keys(list).length );

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer is not helpful; I think you have confused Maps and Sets with ordinary objects. If you read the question you have linked you should notice that it says this method does not work for Maps and Sets. If you read the other answers on this question you would see what the OP's actual problem is. I recommend deleting this answer.

Comment: The main issue here is the incorrect usage of `Map()` as @zero298 mentioned in the comments section of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54518951/#comment95840791_54518951

Answer (score 9):

Map type has a special prototype to get length of the Map object

```
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('a', 'alpha');
map1.set('b', 'beta');
map1.set('g', 'gamma');

console.log(map1.size);
// expected output: 3
```

[Referance from developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size)

Answer (score 6):

Comment to poster's code, the right call should look like samples in this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Depends on data structure, for array like object, we can get map size by:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(responseJson.result.priceMap).length;
```

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length); 
// logs 3
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, we can easily get the length of a map using the size property. The map size property is read only and returns an integer value.

```
const map = new Map();

map.set('foo', 1);
map.set('bar', 2);
map.set('baz', 3);
console.log(map.size); //3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).