# How to check if a Map or Set is empty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With a traditional object in JavaScript, it is easy enough to check if it is empty using the `Object.keys` method:

```
const emptyObj = {};
console.log(Object.keys(emptyObj).length === 0);  // true, i.e. "empty"

const populatedObj = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(Object.keys(populatedObj).length === 0);  // false, not empty
```

Although a bit redundant, you can use the same approach with arrays too if you like:

```
const emptyArr = [];
console.log(Object.keys(emptyArr).length === 0);  // true

const populatedArr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Object.keys(populatedArr).length === 0);  // false
```

However, ES6's handy new data structures *Map* and *Set*, don't work the same way. If you try to use `Object.keys` on them you will *always* get an empty array!

```
const populatedSet = new Set(['foo']);
console.log(Object.keys(populatedSet).length);  // 0

const populatedMap = new Map([['foo', 1]]);
console.log(Object.keys(populatedMap).length);  // 0
```

So what is the best way to check whether or not your fancy new ES6 structures are populated? Also, is there some sort of single overloaded method that would work for objects, arrays, Maps, *and* Sets?

Comment: There is property `.size` for this purpose.

Comment: you would use `map.size`, not `map.length`

Comment: Please make sure to read the documentation on these things as they are amazingly documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: While the size property is certainly documented, it is not obvious, and googling specifically for empty Maps/Sets does not turn up much. So I felt having this specific question documented on StackOverflow would be useful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You use its `size` property. Both Maps and Sets have it ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size)).

```js
const populatedSet = new Set(['foo']);
console.log(populatedSet.size);  // 1

const populatedMap = new Map([['foo', 1]]);
console.log(populatedMap.size);  // 1
```

(Side note: `WeakMap` and `WeakSet` don't have `size` or any way of listing their contents, in order to keep their implementations, and code using them, sane. :-) For the functionality they have in common with `Map` and `Set`, they have the same API, but it's a subset.)

Answer (score 17):

You can check this directly:

```
if (storeMapDetails.size == 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For both cases you can use

```
const populatedSet = new Set(['foo']);
console.log(populatedSet.size); // should be 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that from jQuery

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(your_map_object))
{
    // do something
}
```